# How to strip / discard specified letters from a string in Python?

Tags: python, strip

I am trying to print a sentence in a certain order by having the program print several strings in order and removing an unnecessary 'k' throughout the strings. However, the code will not strip out the 'k.'
The code is below:

```
`calok = ", mke o"
totrentekajah = "Whko's kth"
tilren = "rk ykouk?"
rekajah = "ek gkod hekre"

history = totrentekajah + rekajah + calok + tilren
history = history.strip('k')

print(history)`
```

The output I'm looking for is "Who's the god here, me or you?' Instead, I get:

```
`Whko's kthek gkod hekre, mke ork ykouk?`
```

There is a reason the code has a redundant number of steps for the desired outcome. I don't want to change the format. I would just like to know how you can strip 'k' for the output without actually removing it from the string input.

I tried this code:

```
`calok = ", mke o"
totrentekajah = "Whko's kth"
tilren = "rk ykouk?"
rekajah = "ek gkod hekre"

history = totrentekajah + rekajah + calok + tilren
history = history.strip('k')

print(history)`
```

I expected to get "Who's the god here, me or you?" Instead I got:

```
`Whko's kthek gkod hekre, mke ork ykouk?`
```

Sorry for repeating this. I didn't realise there was another step specifically for this.

Comment: `.strip()` only removes characters at the _start_ and _end_ of the string.  If the character occurs in the _middle_ of the string, it will not be removed.

Comment: Are *all* `k`s unnecessary in this context?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted `.replace()` instead?  `history = history.replace('k', '')`

Answer (score 3):

It suffices to use [`.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
history = history.replace('k', '')
```

---

If there are several characters you wish to discard,
then it's much better to use
[`.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

```
history = 'abc kjijk xyz'

delete = str.maketrans('', '', 'ijk')

assert history.translate(delete) == 'abc  xyz'
```

Why?
If we're scanning a long string,
this technique accomplishes the result in
just a single pass,
without need of several .replace() calls.